# Importing Zbar into C++ project on macOS

Tags: c++, libraries, zbar

I'm trying to use [Zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar) which is a barcode reading library with bindings for different languages and environments. I'm trying to use Zbar with C++. I have written C++ code but I don't know much about importing libraries and setting up my IDE to do that. I'm using Xcode on macOS Sierra. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to the below answer, I was able to get ZBar installed successfully. However, when I try building the following code in Xcode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zbar.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {        
    zbar::ImageScanner scanner;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use **homebrew** to manage all your packages on a Mac since Apple doesn't supply a package manager for some reason. You can grab it from [brew.sh](http://brew.sh).

Once you have that installed, you can simply install `zbar` with:

```
brew install zbar
```

It would be a good idea to install `pkgconfig` too :

```
brew install pkgconfig
```

Now you can compile at the command line with:

```
clang yourProgram.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs zbar) -o yourProg
```

or with C++, or g++:

```
clang++ yourProgram.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs zbar) -o yourProg
```

---

If you want to use  **Xcode**, you need to set up:

- the search path for headers (include files)
- the search path for libraries
- the libraries themselves.

As they are not that simple to find, click on `1` then `2` in the figure below to get to the correct area of Xcode:

[image]

Now set them up like this:

[image]

[image]

And everything should be all good to go - as our American friends say. This method takes advantage of the fact that **homebrew** always puts symbolic links in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` to the latest, greatest version of `zbar` that you have installed. So, if you update any **homebrew** packages, your code will use the latest, greatest versions. You can see the links I am talking about like this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/include | grep zbar 
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    34 13 Mar 12:15 zbar -> ../Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/include/zbar
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    36 13 Mar 12:15 zbar.h -> ../Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/include/zbar.h

ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep zbar 
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin        41 13 Mar 12:15 libzbar.0.dylib -> ../Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/lib/libzbar.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin        35 13 Mar 12:15 libzbar.a -> ../Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/lib/libzbar.a
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin        39 13 Mar 12:15 libzbar.dylib -> ../Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/lib/libzbar.dylib
```

P.S. You update **homebrew** with:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

---

If you want to use a *specific version* of `zbar`, you need to work a little harder.

You get the include path like this:

```
pkg-config --cflags zbar
```

**Sample Output**

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/include
```

And the library path like this:

```
pkg-config --libs zbar
```

**Sample Output**

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/zbar/0.10_4/lib -lzbar
```

Then you put those values into **Xcode** along these lines:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much for the detailed answer, would never have been able to figure this out. I've updated the original post with a build error I'm getting when trying to compile a simple program using one of ZBar's classes. Would appreciate if you could take a look at it.

Comment: I pasted the output of `pkg-config --cflags zbar` in "Other Linker Flags" since the command had the word "flags" in it :) I'm beginning to think this is wrong. What should go in box 3 ? I used the outputs of the commands you provided for "Header Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" (without the  `-I` and `-L` )

Comment: Please look again at the end of my answer - I had a moment to do it more thoroughly - sorry it was a rush last night!

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I want to learn more about the magic that you just walked me through - what's a good place to learn about C++ build processes (rather than just code)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Not sure there is anything that describes all the old junk I know:-) Back in the old days, we used to learn `make` and have `Makefiles` for our command-line projects. Then `cmake` came along and made life easier. Then all the s/w development GUIs came along - Xcode, CLion, Eclipse, Visual Studio, NetBeans, Geany came along for folks who like graphical interfaces. Personally, I tend to use `cmake` and `git` but each to their own. You can Google the name of anything I have mentioned along with `tutorial` and you find something to get you started!

Comment: Great, thanks! I learned a little bit about make but (clearly) wasn't able to translate that knowledge to Xcode. Will check out CMake